# Pyinstaller produces massive folder

Tags: python, splash-screen, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to pack a splash screen, these are the import of the python script:

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango
```

I use the following command to create the dist folder:

```
pyinstaller splash_gui.py
```

The problem is that the produced folder is 630Mb which is an overkill for just a splash screen program, so I investigated further and i find out that i could remove a LOT of files (the most heavy were the one in the share folder containing my themes, all of them) but more importantly i found out that the vast majority of dynamic libraries were useless.

With trial and error I managed to remove all the things that were not necessary (often generating a warning which i don't care because it is just a splash screen). Is there a direct way to avoid this mess? Briefly i want to keep just the file containing actual called functions.

This is the before and after clean situation:

```
630Mb                               8Mb
.                                   .
└── splash_gui                      └── splash_gui
    ├── array.so                        ├── binascii.so
    ...                                 ├── _collections.so
    ├── share                           ├── cPickle.so
    │   ├── fontconfig                  ├── cStringIO.so
    │   ├── glib-2.0                    ├── fcntl.so
    │   ├── icons                       ├── _functools.so
    │   ├── locale                      ├── gi._gi.so
    │   ├── mime                        ├── _io.so
    │   └── themes                      ├── itertools.so
    ...                                 ├── libpython2.7.so.1.0
    ├── _sha.so                         ├── math.so
    ├── _socket.so                      ├── _multiprocessing.so
    ├── splash_gui                      ├── operator.so
    ├── _ssl.so                         ├── _random.so
    ├── strop.so                        ├── select.so
    ├── _struct.so                      ├── _socket.so
    ├── termios.so                      ├── splash_gui
    ├── time.so                         ├── _struct.so
    ├── unicodedata.so                  ├── time.so
    └── zlib.so                         └── zlib.so
```

Except for the warnings the splash screen works normal

Comment: Is it OK to *just* produce an exe, and not the folders?

Comment: only if the exe is small, a big exe will create a delay in the splash screen appearance

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller packs all your installed librarieswith pip ,so you need to create a clean new virtual environment and only install packages that you need in that environment, when you do that install pyinstaller inside and run it

Answer (score 0):

If a .exe file (and no other folders/files) is acceptable (really just try it out if you need to chack the file size), Here is my solution, running the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile "directory\script_name.py"
```

In the current directory, a bunch of new folders will be made. Here's what to do with them:

1. Your file will be in "dist", and will be called script_name (without ".py", of course
2. The folders "dist" and "build" are unnecessary, as well as `__pycache__` if it comes up
3. Also, the file "script_name".spec will be created.

Comment: this will produce an archive with all the file inside, it is true that it will be lighter (like 300mb) but it will be painfully slow. I don't want to just hide them...

Comment: Yah this is what I do, I don't really know another way, so this is just to get you started.